# How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP? without form and submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple HTML file.
In this HTML file I have a table with rows and columns.
In another PHP file.
I have a code that takes my bank info MYSQL information
Now I am trying to send from the first HTML file to PHP.
Every  tag has an attribute.
Home and guest.
Send 2 VAR to PHP and then load the PHP page with the information I sent.
Now I ask you. Is my method correct?
Is there any other way to do it?
Thank you very much to everyone who read all the code.
And trying to help me.

**HTML**

```js
$("th").click(function() {
  var home = $(this).attr("home");
  var guest = $(this).attr("guest");
  $.post("getBetsTeam.php", {
      home: home,
      guest: guest
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      $("#controler").html(response);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="without" home="Liverpool" guest="Bolton">Liverpool-Bolton</th>
      <td>3.3</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>2.8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="without" home="manchster united" guest="newcasel">manchster united-newcasel</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($link,'bet369');

if(!link){
    //echo "connection to db feild!";
}else{
    //echo "conection succesful!!! </br>";
}

if(mysqli_select_db($link,'bet369')){
    //echo "db selected! <br>";
} ?>
<?php
    $fr = 'Fulltime Result';
    $home = $_POST['home'];
    $guest = $_POST['guest'];
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from bets where line='$fr' and home='$home' and guest='$guest'");
    $rows =mysqli_fetch_row($res);
    if ($rows[0] == 0) {
    die;
}
else{
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from bets where line='$fr'");
   //if ($rows[0] == 1) {
    echo '
    <div class="headBets" style="color:white; with:100%; text-align: center; background-color: #0c15d2;">Fulltime Result</div>
    <table>';

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {

echo '<tr>';
//echo '<th class="without">'; echo $row[home] . '-' . $row[guest]; echo '</th>';
echo '<td class="with" cheak="0" idbet="'.$row[idbet].'"numid="'. $row[idbet].'AAbet" a="0" b="0" c="0" d="0" e="0" f="0" z="1" value="'.$row[bethome].'"'.'team="'.$row[home].'  v  '.$row[guest].'"choice="'.$row[home].'"liga="'.$row[liga].'"line="'.$row[line].'">'.$row[home]. "   ".$row[bethome].'</td>';
echo '<td class="with" cheak="0" idbet="'.$row[idbet].'"numid="'. $row[idbet].'XXbet" a="0" b="0" c="0" d="0" e="0" f="0" z="x" value="'.$row[betdraw].'"'.'team="'.$row[home].'  v  '.$row[guest].'"choice="'.$row[draw].'"liga="'.$row[liga].'"line="'.$row[line].'">'.$row[draw]. "   ".$row[betdraw].'</td>';
echo '<td class="with" cheak="0" idbet="'.$row[idbet].'"numid="'. $row[idbet].'BBbet" a="0" b="0" c="0" d="0" e="0" f="0" z="2" value="'.$row[betguest].'"'.'team="'.$row[home].'  v  '.$row[guest].'"choice="'.$row[guest].'"liga="'.$row[liga].'"line="'.$row[line].'">'.$row[guest]. "   ".$row[betguest].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        }
        if(mysqli_query){
            //echo "all data reload !";
        }
echo    '</table>';
//  }
}
?>
```

Comment: @micaro I already know the information you wrote me.
Do not understand your answer ... Why did I ask?
I'm looking for a simple answer ...
How can I send varibale without approval of form ...
Hope it's clear now ...

Comment: If I understand you right - Ajax is the way to send information in such way.

Comment: @Picard Yes, you understand me.
But it is important to mention again I have no form ...
Only table with rows and columns ...
I do not have a confirmation button ...
Just a table ..

Comment: You have to execute the Ajax call (which will collect and send the data you need) on some event like page load https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ so it will go automatically.

Comment: @Picard I know how to use any AJAX syntax.
But to my question I can not just use the load ()

Comment: Create PHP Session variables with names of variables and initialize them to null (or 0). 
Create a <div> with display:none , some name and some ID. Send the data to that <div> via JS and fetch it in PHP using session variable?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to...

> *"Send 2 VAR to PHP and then load the PHP page with the information I sent*"

then it sounds like you want to create a form and submit it in your `<th>` click handler

```
const form = document.createElement('form')
form.action = 'getBetsTeam.php'
form.method = 'post'

const homeInput = document.createElement('input')
homeInput.type = 'hidden'
homeInput.name = 'home'
homeInput.value = home
form.appendChild(homeInput)

// repeat for guest

document.body.appendChild(form)
form.submit()
```

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand you. I do not have a form to send in my file. And also i need after sending to php. Php will return the information I sent.